# Confusion Over jQuery Events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have just started to use jQuery and have run into a problem regarding events.

Below is my code, it creates a div element on the page, I would like to attach an event handler to this div that reacts if it is clicked or double clicked. I thought the following code would work but it doesn't seem to work at all:

```
this.mainAppDiv = document.createElement("div");
this.mainAppDiv.id = "mainBody";
this.mainAppDiv.style.width = "99%";
this.mainAppDiv.style.height = this.mainCanvasDiv_H;
this.mainAppDiv.style.border = "thin red dashed";

document.body.appendChild(this.mainAppDiv);

$(this.mainAppDiv).click(function()
{
    alert("The Clicked Divs ID: " + this.mainAppDiv.id);
});
```

When the event is fired is should simply alert what DIV element was clicked but I get the following error in firebug:

> this.mainAppDiv is undefined
> line 43 - **alert("The Clicked Divs ID: " + this.mainAppDiv.id);**

Can anyone see why this would not work?

Answer (score 2):

You're guilty of `this` abuse.

-- this == window

`$(this.mainAppDiv).click(function()`
{

-- this == dom object clicked

`alert("The Clicked Divs ID: " + this.mainAppDiv.id);`

Simple answer is change to:

```
$(this.mainAppDiv).click(function(e)
{
    alert("The Clicked Divs ID: " + e.target.id);
});
```

But bigger picture use selectors instead of `this` to find things. `this` is not portable and should be avoided unless you really want to refer to a specific context. And it can be redefined - if you have, say, a function in an object which uses `this` to refer to the object it's part of, and you bind that to a jQuery click event, `this` would refer to thing that was clicked, and not the object. Your code wouldn't work at all if you moved it to a function or object.  e.g. do this instead.

`$('#mainAppDiv').click(..)`

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not the same element within the handler.  Inside the handler, `this` refers to the element that was clicked to which the handler was applied.

```
$('div').attr('id','mainBody')
        .css( { width: '99%',
                height: $('#mainCanvasDiv').height(),
                border-style: 'dashed',
                border-width: 'thin',
                border-color: 'red'
         })
        .click( function() {
             alert('The clicked Divs ID: ' + this.id );
         })
        .appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `this` refers to the element the event handler is bound to.... not necessarily the element that was clicked (event bubbling).

Comment: @Felix -- point taken, but technically if you click on an element contained within another element, you're clicking on the outer element as well.  I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` inside that event handler will not refer to the same object as it did when the handler was defined and passed to jQuery.  It'll be a reference to the target `<div>` you created (assuming that setup for the event handler actually works).

You can simplify that code a lot:

```
var self = this;
${'body').append($('<div></div>', {
  id: 'mainBody',
  css: {width: '99%', height: self.mainCanvasDiv_H, borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 'thin', borderStyle: 'dashed' },
  click: function() {
    alert("Clicked ID: " + this.id);
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

As they are created runtime , you have to use live instead of click

http://api.jquery.com/live/

jquery live should help

As others mentioned you have two problems in your code , you still need to use jquery live...a s you are creating the div  dynamically

Comment: He's attaching the event handler directly to the DOM element, which *might* work; I'll have to fiddle it.